# Remove '#empty_option' and '#empty_value' from select list after choosing some option

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with an entity reference select list where I need to add some default value `#empty_value` with `#empty_option` without any referenced entity. How to remove that option from the select list when some other option was selected from the list?

```
function hook_form_alter() {
  if (isset($form['field_needs']) && isset($form['field_delivery'])) {
    $form['field_needs']['widget']['#empty_option'] = t("Needs");
    $form['field_delivery_area']['widget']['#empty_option'] = t('Delivery zone');
  }
}
```

I have a content type with entity_reference field type, where can be referenced some form and in node I want add a default item, that will have any value (by default for select was added a first referenced item from entites array). Altering form with checking fields (field_needs and field_delvery_area) in that case works ok because this fields reusable in several existing forms where I need to add a "default option" (but `#default_value` should be an array of refferenced taxonomies as I understand so I add "default" value using `#empty_option`

Comment: Can you try to provide an example?

Comment: @leymannx from `hook_form_alter`
`if (isset($form['field_needs']) && isset($form['field_delivery'])){
    $form['field_needs']['widget']['#empty_option'] = t("Needs");
    $form['field_delivery_area']['widget']['#empty_option'] = t('Delivery zone');
  }`

widget is coming from rendering from content-type field with entity_reference form

Comment: Sorry, I mean an use case. A real world example. 

Comment: @leymannx that's real example what I have :) I have a content type with `entity_reference` field type, where can be referenced some form and in node I want add a default item, that will have any value (by default for select was added a first referenced item from entites array). Altering form with checking fields (`field_needs` and `field_delvery_area`) in that case works ok because this fields reusable in several existing forms where I need to add a "default option" (but `#default_value` should be an array of refferenced taxonomies as I understand so I add "default" value using `#empty_option`